# sorting values in xml file not sorting last 4 values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<listGroup name="Chemistry Lists">
  <chemistryAnalysisMethod tableName="List Chemistry Analysis Method">
    <option>
      <Value>BTEX</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Carbonates</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Chlorinated Hydrocarbons</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Explosives</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Halogenated Hydrocarbons</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Heavy Metals</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Herbicides</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Metals</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>OCP</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Organophosphorus Pesticides</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Organotins</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>PAH</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>PAH/Phenols</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>PCB</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Pesticides</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Phenols</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Phthalates</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>SVOC</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>TPH</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>VOC</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Dissolved Mercury by FIMS</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Dissolved Metals by ICPMS</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>Nitrite and Nitrate</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
    <option>
      <Value>OE - Wet</Value>
      <ContainerType />
      <RequiredVolume />
      <Preservative />
      <HoldTime />
      <NumberofJars />
      <Filtered>false</Filtered>
    </option>
  </chemistryAnalysisMethod> 
</listGroup>
```

I want to sort by the `Value` element and I wrote the following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">   
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />   
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />   

  <xsl:template match="/serverInterface">
    <interface>
      <xsl:attribute name="firstFormAPIName">
    <xsl:value-of select="@firstFormAPIName"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:for-each select="listGroup/*">
    <xsl:sort select="@tableName" />
    <xsl:element name="list">
      <xsl:attribute name="tableName">
        <xsl:value-of select="@tableName" />
      </xsl:attribute>       
    </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:for-each select="form">
    <xsl:if test="not(@enabled) or @enabled='always' or @enabled='yes'">
      <xsl:element name="form">
        <xsl:attribute name="apiName">
          <xsl:value-of select="@apiName" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="title">
          <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="template">
          <xsl:value-of select="@template" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="fieldDataTableName">
          <xsl:value-of select="@fieldDataTableName" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:if test="not(@apiName='projectForm')">
          <xsl:attribute name="parentFieldDataTableName">
        <xsl:value-of select="@parentFieldDataTableName" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(name()='group') and not(name()='serverInterface') and not(name()='list')]" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:for-each select="group">
      <xsl:if test="not(@enabled) or @enabled='always' or @enabled='yes'">
        <xsl:element name="form">
          <xsl:attribute name="apiName">
        <xsl:value-of select="@apiName" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="template">
        <xsl:value-of select="@template" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="fieldDataTableName">
        <xsl:value-of select="../@fieldDataTableName" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="parentFieldDataTableName">
        <xsl:value-of select="../@parentFieldDataTableName" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(name()='group') and not(name()='serverInterface') and not(name()='list')]" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </interface>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:apply-templates>   
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="listGroup/chemistryAnalysisMethod">
    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:sort select="Value"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>   
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="option">
    <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>   
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(name()='group') and not(name()='serverInterface') and not(name()='list')]">
    <xsl:if test="not(@enabled) or @enabled='always' or @enabled='yes'">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="name()='shortcut'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='label'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='blowCount'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='photo'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='color'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='munsellColor'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='advancementMethod'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='button'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='constituentPercentages'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='orientation'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='gpsControl'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='constituents'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='rockType'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@requiredValue='always' or @requiredValue='yes'">
        <xsl:attribute name="requiredValue">true</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="apiName">
          <xsl:value-of select="@apiName" />
        </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:attribute name="requiredValue">false</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="apiName">
          <xsl:value-of select="@apiName" />
        </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:for-each select="@*[not(name()='requiredValue' or name()='enabled' or name()='moveable')]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>   
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I am trying to do so no transformation is done.

Comment: Are you sure you have posted the correct XSLT? The one here does not work: see [here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/PY06A6). The `for-each` on "chemistryAnalysisMethod" will not work because you are at the "serverInterface" level when you use it. The `for-each`-es on "form" and "group" will not do anything because these elements do not exist in your XML. Additionally, XSLT is case-sensitive and the "value" in your `xsl-sort` does not match the "Value" in your XML

Comment: i have written code after interface also but doesnot work can u help me out from this

Comment: I'll try to help but can you provide an example of the XML you are trying to produce from this input?

Comment: hi benL the code which i have given is the xml file an d i wnat to sort the element "value"

Answer (score 0):

If *all* you want to is output the same XML, but with `option` elements sorted by `Value`, then the following XSLT stylesheet will do that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- This is a modified identity transform. -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Simply copy all attributes and child nodes, except for option nodes. -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::option)]"/>
      <!-- Copy out all child option nodes, but order them by Value. -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="option">
        <xsl:sort select="Value"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, it looks like you're trying to do additional transformations in your example XSLT. I can't be sure what they are without an example of the XML you want to achieve.